# From Datalist to Edit.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a real estate website and I am using a datalist (ASP.NET / C#) to show listing, my next step which i can't figure out how to do it, is if I click on the link 'edit', Select information for that specific house and show it in the Edit.aspx and each field of the datalist is shown in a textbox.

My database is pretty easy with just 4 fields : IDhouse, Price, Bedroom, ImgHouse.

Please if someone can help me I will appreciate it so much, thank you.

Code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="IDhouse" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"/>
                        <ItemStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style2">
                                    Price : <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price", "{0:C}") %>' /><br />
                                    Beds : <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Bedroom") %>' /><br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server">Delete</asp:HyperLink>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">Edite</asp:HyperLink>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="style1">
                                        <asp:Image  ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="201px" Width="331px"  
                                            ImageUrl='<%# "~/DisplayImg.ashx?IDhouse="+ Eval("IDhouse") %>'/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </ItemTemplate>


      </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">Edite</asp:HyperLink>
```

with

```
<a href="Edit.aspx?id=<%# Eval("IDhouse") %>">Edit</a>
```

and on the Edit.aspx page, load the required data based on the IDhouse value obtained from the querystring

Comment: you might want to change the "" from the actual href to ''